# how catch error in CoreData with MergePolicy

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
DataBaseService.getContext().mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.error
Unique attribute is phone.
```

When I again save object with current phone my application crashing with next:

```
fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x600000071cc0) for constraint
```

How i can catch this error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but you could wrap the save command in a do-catch block and then check the type of error on the catch statement.

```
  do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
      print (error)
      //Custom logic to handle error
    }
```

This link helped me out when I ran into a similar issue [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1]